# How can changing the size of the string to be scanned affect the output completely independent of it?

Tags: string

My code was giving wrong answer on problem 400A on http://codeforces.com while it was working fine on my laptop. Somebody suggested to me that the problem can be solved by increasing the size of my string and after doing that, the code got accepted. To find the mistake in my original code, I placed print statements in the two codes to find out what is going wrong and made two submissions in codeforces. In the following submissions, I just changed the size of array `w` from 12 to 13:
http://codeforces.com/contest/400/submission/5948686

http://codeforces.com/contest/400/submission/5948717

As you can see, in the former case, the inner loop is not executed for `i=0` but in the later case it is. Why is this happening (I know that string size must be kept greater than the string but how is this related to the functioning of the inner loop at `i=0`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my best guess, but it depends on the compiler used, how the memory way laid out, - there may be no way to know for sure. Someone else may have a better guess.

So here's what maybe happened: scanf read in 13 characters - the 12 characters, plus a null terminating character (\0). The null terminator has a ascii value of 0

The 12 characters were thrown into the buffer correctly, and then the \0 character **maybe** overwrote the first value of `ar`. So the inner loop became for(j=0; j < 0; j++)

Moral of the story is that buffer overflows are bad.

Comment: Thank you, what you said is indeed happening. ar[0] becomes zero after the scanf statement. I printed the value of ar[0] after the scanf statement and the result was 0:  [result](http://codeforces.com/contest/400/submission/5949040)